# CiviCRM Spark updates fail due to lack of read permissions on directory

Tags: directory, civicrm-spark, php8

I am using CiviCRM Spark. I don't believe I can change permissions on directories (?). These are the errors:

```
Error: Your extensions directory (/var/aegir/platforms/civicrm-d7/web/sites/atcni.civicrm.org/modules/extensions) is read-only.If you would like to perform downloads or upgrades, then change the file permissions.

This system uses PHP version 8.0.30. This meets the minimum recommendations and you do not need to upgrade immediately, but the preferred version is 8.1.0.
```

This is the joblog:

```
2024-01-03 14:00:10 CiviCRM Update Check    
Entity: Job Action: version_check
Summary
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: File not writable
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: File not writable

Scheduled Job CiviCRM Update Check is failing. Error was: Finished execution of CiviCRM Update Check with result: Failure, Error message: File not writable
CiviCRM Patch Available
```

Comment: If this has already been asnswered in chat.civicrm.org then you're welcome to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually three separate alerts here. I don't think any of these is really a problem and you can safely ignore all three of them.

CiviCRM Spark is a managed system and is deliberately configured so that users are unable to alter directory permissions or install/update extensions.

The message about the PHP version is just saying that PHP 8.1 is preferred. CiviCRM will run fine on PHP 8.0.

The job log is indicating that it was not possible to check for updates. Note that this is just a check to see if there is a new update available it isn't actually performing the update.

Updates are managed by CiviCRM Spark so there is nothing that you need to do (or can do) in any case.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, William! I guess I thought the lack of access might have something to do with the reason that every time I try to login, I have to create a new password. It doesn't seem to be saving my login. I understand this is a hosted service and I chose it so I wouldn't have to administer the server, but in the settings, I see some things (such as permissions for anonymous) that make me think maybe I need to configure something properly. New to civiCRM Spark, so am actually quite clueless. I apologize. Ter

Comment: No need to apologise! It's a reasonable question to ask. Ideally the first alert should be hidden from users as it isn't anything that you can change. I'm not sure why you have to create a new password every time you log in. That doesn't sound right. You shouldn't have to do that.